# c for loop break statement doesn't work

Tags: c, string, loops, search, strstr

I've written a `for loop` that searches a string in another. I want it to rename it's position when it finds it. ( *I am open for new suggestions for the search :)* )

```
int search (char str1[56], char str2[5]){
    int c1, c2, c3, c4;
    c1 = 0;

    for (c1=0; c1<56; c1++)
    {
        c2 = 0, c3 = 0;
        for (c2 = 0; c2 < 5; c2++){
            if (str1[c1] == str2[c2]){
                c3++;
            }
        }

        if (c3 == 5){
            c4 = c1; 
            break;
        }
    }

    return c4;
}
```

Comment: Define `doesn't work`

Comment: Did you try to debug? It is very helpful.

Comment: i tried that but it wasn't so helpful.

Comment: what do you mean with "doesn't work" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int search(const char str1[56], const char str2[5]){
    int c1, c2;
    int len1 = strlen(str1);
    int len2 = strlen(str2);

    for (c1=0; c1<len1-len2+1; ++c1){
        for (c2 = 0; c2 < len2; ++c2)
            if (str1[c1+c2] != str2[c2])
                break;
        if (c2 == len2)
            return c1;
    }

    return -1;//not found
}
int main(void){//DEMO
    const char *test_data[] = { "test", "the", "pro", "gram", "hte" };
    int i, size = sizeof(test_data)/sizeof(*test_data);
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        int result;
        result=search("test the program!", test_data[i]);
        printf("%d\n", result);//0, 5, 9, 12, -1
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, this was most helpful. one last thing, I couldn't understand what you did here: `int i, size = sizeof(test_data)/sizeof(*test_data);` would you mind explaining it to me? :)

Comment: @cskr It is asking (eg case of `test_data[5]` is 5) the size of the array. You will be prompted by dividing size of the contents of one of the array (eg sizeof(*test_data)) the overall size of the array(eg `sizeof(test_data)`)  by using the `sizeof` operator. That way, followed by the addition of data This is useful sometimes.

Comment: case of `char*` (eg size = 8): `char *array[5]` : sizeof(array) == total size 40, sizeof(array[0]) == one element size 8, 5 == 40/8.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want `strstr()`, it searches for a substring in a string and returns a pointer to it if found. Strings aren't the best thing to start with when learning C, you really want to use proper libraries for that at first.

Comment: I would look for the current implementation of strstr() as well. One example is here: http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_standard_library:string.h:strstr

Comment: I tried using 'strstr' but didn't succeeded it. I couldn't return the point of match. How can I return the match point with 'strstr' ?

Comment: `strstr()` returns a pointer to the match point.  If you want an integer index, you can then subtract the address of the string from the address returned by `strstr()` and you will get an integer difference.

Comment: But I'm trying to find the c1 value for the match? Will that difference **absolutely** give me that?

Answer (score 1):

in the innermost for loop you iterate over all characters of `str2`, but compare each of them to the same position in `str1`

```
for (c2=0; c2<5; c2++) {
    if (str1[c1] == str2[c2]) {
        c3++;
    }
}
```

what you want is to iterate over the characters of `str1` too, i.e.

```
for (c2=0; c2<5; c2++) {
    if (str1[c1+c2] == str2[c2]) {
        c3++;
    }
}
```

this will run out of bounds on `str1`, you can fix this by searching only up to position `length(str1) - length(str2) + 1`

```
for (c1=0; c1<56-4; c1++) {
```

you should however consider not using hardcoded string lengths

Comment: Still does not match only at the end, perhaps.

Comment: In addition, it is necessary to initialize (eg -1) the c4.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that I cannot run out of bounds for this assignment so harcoding is helping me.

Comment: But I tried your suggestion for the solution (c1+c2) but I still cannot found the matching value of c1?

Comment: Did you also change the `56-4` upper bound? I just ran it and it works.

Comment: yeah I changed it but result is still zero.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jite suggested, you can go for `strstr()`, that's the best option. If you want add another flavor to your search, regarding comparing two strings while `iGnOrInG` the case, you can give a try to `strcasestr()`.

> While using either of them, don't forget to include string.h

Check out the [man page of strstr()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) for more information. Also, for sample usage check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm).